# Error in view: The asset "ABCD" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am migrating from carrierwave to active storage so I added following change in model along with `Installation` and `Configuration` changes mentioned on this [doc](https://huy-hoang.medium.com/from-carrierwave-to-active-storage-b2fd3e71407f)

Model:

```
  mount_uploader :file, PatientUploader
  has_one_attached :file_new
```

I am able to successfully test the changes through a rake task but now I am trying to test it from UI by uploading a pdf file. I can also test the changes with the view changes as is but later I'll be removing the mount_uploader change (all carrierwave changes) so I'll have to update view hence I tried following change in view.

I updated following line in view
from

```
= link_to patient.name, patient.file_url, target: "_blank", class: 'external'
```

to

```
= link_to image_tag(patient.name), patient.file, target: "_blank", class: 'external'
```

but I got the error `The asset "ABCD" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

I dont have `config.assets.compile` set anywhere in project since I saw on some stack threads its not a good practice.

I am wondering why I am getting this error after updating view and any idea how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `image_tag` the `patient.name`, but [`image_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) needs a viable `source`:

> The source can be a full path, a file, or an Active Storage attachment.

If `patient.file` is an Active Storage attachment:

```rb
link_to edit_patient_path(patient), target: "_blank", class: 'external' do
  image_tag(patient.file)
```

I entered `edit_patient_path(patient)` as the `url` for the link because I don't know where you're trying to have this link take the user on click.

It seems in the old link, you were using `patient.name` as the body of the link and the `url` was to `patient.file_url`.

In the new link, it seems like you want the body to be the image, but the URL you want to take them to is unclear to me.

---

Also, you can take a look at [`link_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) to better understand what to pass as variables in what order:

> link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)

Note that because `image_tag()` is complex, `link_to()` should become a block to keep things clear.